# Lubuntu 16.04 iphone won't mount

Tags: lubuntu, iphone

I am using the latest LTS release of Lubuntu. I am using an iPhone 6, and I've checked synaptic package manager to see that libimobiledevice is installed, along with some other supposedly mandatory packages to use linux to manage an iDevice. The problem is, now the iPhone won't mount. I used to have a problem where when I connected it, TWO options called "iPhone" would appear in the left bar in the file browser. But now, nothing happens. The phone simply charges without mounting.

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 1525.

It seems that all "solutions" I found online were not up to date because they were talking about iOS 7 or even iOS 4.2. I'm far past that, after all, I'm using an iPhone 6.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16 + iPhone 5 and I have the same issue unfortunately.